# Online highscore for my game

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm creating a game using c# and I would like an online highscore board.
I prefer the highscore to be stored in a MySQL-database but other ways will also work.

Please point me to the right direction.

Edit, more information:

I am using MySQL at localhost, dbname: diggangames.
The game I'm creating in C# is a basic console application and the score is calculated in the end, that score + a string + a timestamp I want to insert into the database. After the insert I want to view the table with entry's

Comment: What specific technical problem are you encountering?

Comment: @Rex M: I don't know how to code it, I need hints how to accomplish the highscore-table.

Comment: Provide more context and the community will be better able to help.  For instance, do you have a db at all at this point?  At least give us some detailed functional requirements.

Comment: if you dont know how to insert data from C# this is the place for you to start http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3399475/mysql-with-c-from-a-php-developers-standpoint then if you already nailed down this part what you want to acomplish next ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need a web site, or at least some other service on the network that will talk to the database.  (You don't want anyone connecting directly to the server, as any program that does will need to have the password -- and someone inclined to mess with your data could get that password in the assembly with very little trouble.)

On the server, it depends what language/platform you use.  For web / MySQL, i'd recommend PHP, as it come semi built with support.  And frankly, it's easier to start with than ASP.net is.

Once you have something to handle that access, in your C# app, you can use a WebRequest to post the info and see the response.  Something like this:

```
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("http://my.site.com/reportscore");
req.Method = "POST";
req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"; // or something like that

Stream reqStream = req.GetRequestStream();
byte[] encoded = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("score=12345&name=Somebody");
reqStream.Write(encoded, 0, encoded.Length);
reqStream.Close();

WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
```

The response object will have a stream you can use to read the data the server sent back.

Something to keep in mind, though...anyone that knows this URL, and what to send, could mess with your scores and give themselves a score of 24246246624245245245 if you don't have some way to validate the score.

Comment: I'm already familiar with PHP so that is very good, could you give me any examples how I could use Post and PHP with C# Console Application?

Comment: You should be able to add the needed references and then use a WebRequest to post the info.  The client doesn't care whether the server's running PHP, ASP.net, or anything else, as long as it speaks HTTP.

Comment: This code you posted give me this as error message: "Error 1 No overload for method 'Write' takes '1' arguments" This is the row that the error is in: "reqStream.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("score=12345&name=Somebody"));"

Comment: @Victor: Updated.  I haven't worked with raw streams much as of late.

Comment: The code almost works perfectly, only one "=" after "req.ContentType" is missing but got it working, thanks for helping! :)

Comment: Code's fixed.  Thanks for noticing the = :)

Answer (score 1):

Start here:  http://www.15seconds.com/issue/050210.htm

It's a tutorial for using ASP.NET to connect to and read from/update MySql.

Connecting to and using MySql from a Console app is pretty much the same as with ASP.Net, so this will be helpful...

But it sounds like what you need is a mentor, or more time learning the basics.

Answer (score 1):

here are couple of link not directly in Asp.net but can get you started quickly.

http://code.google.com/p/scoreninja/

a simple application that you can upload on google app engine and start using it for your own high score data storage.

there is also one similar for android.

http://www.andoop.com/ahighscore